# Android textview setVisibilty GONE not woking

Tags: android, textview

I have a problem with a textview within a recyclerview layout. If I call the setVisibility GONE method, it has no effect, the textview continues to be visible superimposed on the recyclerview although the defined layout does not allow it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#DDDDDD"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#999999"
    android:text="@string/label_object_empty" /></LinearLayout>
```

The code where I carry out the operation is:

```
    recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    OggettoAdapter adapter = new OggettoAdapter(getContext(), oggetti, mapQuartieri, mapDomini,     getOnActionActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (adapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

[image]

If it is useful, the code is executed in an onPostExecute, and is in the main fragment

I tried all sorts of ways, including the textview in a layout, but no, nothing had any effect. I do not know how to do.
Thank you

OnCreateView:

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_oggetti, container, false);

    //ltContainer = root.findViewById(R.id.lt_container);

    tvEmpty = root.findViewById(R.id.tv_empty);
    tvEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.list);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);


    getOnActionActivity().setOnClickListenerMap(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (oggetti != null && !oggetti.isEmpty()) {
                getOnActionActivity().openMap(oggetti, filter.getRaggio(), "POINT (40.83035550115621 14.244734405325753)");
            }
        }
    });

    getOnActionActivity().setOnClickListenerFilter(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getOnActionActivity().openFilter();
        }
    });

    getOnActionActivity().viewIconFilter(true);
    getOnActionActivity().viewIconMap(true);

    return root;
}
```

Update Adapter:

```
adapter = new OggettoAdapter(getContext(), oggetti, mapQuartieri, mapDomini,
```

getOnActionActivity());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

public class OggettoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OggettoAdapter.ViewHolderObjects> {

```
private Context context;
private List<Gs001Oggetto> objects;
private Map<Integer, String> quartieri;
private Map<Integer, String> domini;
private String apiKey;
private OnActionActivity onActionActivity;

public OggettoAdapter(Context context, List<Gs001Oggetto> objects, Map<Integer, String> quartieri, Map<Integer, String> domini, OnActionActivity onActionActivity) {
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.quartieri = quartieri;
    this.domini = domini;
    this.apiKey = context.getString(R.string.map_api_key);
    this.onActionActivity = onActionActivity;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolderObjects onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_object, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolderObjects(itemView, onActionActivity);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderObjects holder, int position) {
    Gs001Oggetto object = objects.get(position);
    holder.oggetto = object;
    String quartiere = quartieri.get(new Integer((int) object.getQuartiere()));
    if (quartiere != null) {
        holder.tvQurtiere.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tvQurtiere.setText(quartiere);
    } else {
        holder.tvQurtiere.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    String descrizioneDom = domini.get(new Integer(object.getDominio()));

    if (descrizioneDom != null) {
        holder.tvDominio.setText(descrizioneDom);
    }

    final String[] coordinate = GeoUtil.convertWktToArray(object.getGeometriaWKT());
    if (coordinate != null && coordinate.length == 2) {
        String sw_url = GeoUtil.createUrlStreeView(coordinate[0] + "," + coordinate[1], 600, 600, apiKey);
        Glide.with(context).load(sw_url).placeholder(R.drawable.thumbnail).into(holder.ivPhoto);
    }

    holder.tvId.setText("" + object.getId());

    String address = object.getToponimo() != null ? object.getToponimo() + " " + object.getStrada() : object.getStrada();
    holder.tvAddress.setText(address);
    holder.layout.setOnClickListener(holder);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return objects.size();
}
```

....

Comment: What is missing here is when and where you set items of the adapter. If you never set them, `adapter.getItemCount()` will always be 0. A few things: you only have to create the create the LayoutManager and Adapter once, best to do this on `onViewCreated()` of your fragment. Make the adapter global to your fragment, set the result in onPostExecute to the adapter. Also don't forget to call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to do as you said but it still doesn't work. As you can see from the image getItemCount is not zero. But anyway from the layout definition recyclerview and textview cannot be overlapped. It is not a relativelayout

Comment: Could you show use the code where you set the items in the adapter and where you cal `tvEmpty = findViewById()`?

Answer (score 1):

1. `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F` to search "Nessun oggetto trovato" and "label_object_empty" to check whether another view is showing the message or just `tvEmpty` is showing that.
2. If you assure that only `tvEmpty` shows the message. Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`R` and replace `tvEmpty.setVisibility(VISIBLE)` to `tvEmpty.setVisibility(GONE)` one by one. Each time you replace one, re-run your app and check whether or not the text is visible or not. If at a change, the text disappears as you expect then carefully review your code, check condition statements to know why your program runs to that line of code.

In your case, I think you have set the text "Nessun oggetto trovato" to other views somewhere.

Comment: Thanks I solved the problem. They were two overlapping fragments, not two views. The same fragment was added twice